# How do you translate "trustee"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to translate "board of trustee". For now I found "estraro de kuratoraro". While "estratro" seems find to me, although "konsilo" or "komitato" might also works as far as I understand the concept of a board. I'm less confident with "kurator/ar/o". [Majstro](http://www.majstro.com/Web/Majstro/bdict.php?gebrTaal=eng&bronTaal=eng&doelTaal=epo&teVertalen=trustee) also propose *komisiito* and *sindiko*. And Apertium  propose *fideikomisulo*, where you can find the *fid/* lexem matching the English *trust*.

I am not a lawyer, let alone a juridic expert on common wealth specific subtleties, but I guess that a curator and a trustee are not the same thing.

If you are aware of legal domain dictionary/resources, it would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kuratoro = trustee

Aro = Group or collection

Kuratoraro = A board of trustees

Comment: Do you have some authoritative source for this translation of trustee?

Comment: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kurato.html#kurato.0o.JUR